# Error: Invalid hook call at Provider, while rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, syntax-error, provider

I'm creating a simple react-redux application. But I stuck at the App.js file. If I add a Provider, it appear an err.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import CakeContainer from './components/CakeContainer';
import store from './redux/store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className='App'>
          <CakeContainer />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );

export default App;
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVDKV.png)

github link: https://github.com/Alex-Choi0/react-redux

You could download the code from my github link.

If I remove the Provider, it works well.

[image: Folder Structure]
[image: Error message]

Comment: When you check my github link, download the branch 15_Actions.

Comment: I checked out your repo and tried to start it but "react-redux" wasn't in the package.json so I had to install this and then it worked perfectly on my side.. if thats not the problem please provide a screenshot with the error in the console or sth :)

Comment: Thank you davbuc. I didn't expect 'react-redux' module. I thought I installed it but it wosn't.